# Jupyter Notebook import all functions from a python file in parent's sibiling directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The following is the tree of the files located:

```
Dir1
- file.py
Dir2
- current.ipynb
```

The jupyter notebook server is running on a docker container.
I would like to import all functions from file.py to current.ipynb and here is what I have tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/serverRoot/home/steven/code/Dir1")

from Dir1.file import *
```

I would like to know what I have done wrong.

UPDATES

Here is the error message I got from jupyter notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2940538/1028217147.py in <module>
      2 sys.path.append("/serverRoot/home/steven/code/Dir1")
      3 
----> 4 from Dir1.file import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Dir1'
```

Comment: _I would like to know what I have done wrong_ You haven't told us what the actual problem is.  If you're getting errors, or other unwanted behavior, then you have to TELL US ABOUT IT.  You can't just throw code at us and ask "What did I do wrong", with no explanation of the actual problem...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problem is that you need to add the absolute path, on my case I would do:
sys.path.append("C:users/Documents/serverRoot/home/steven/code/Dir1")

I hope this helps.